# Is there a way to open a series of new terminal window, and run commands in a single script?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

Every day I do the following commands:

[0] Start terminal

1. Open window -> `memcached`
2. Open window -> `redis-server`
3. Open window -> `memcached`
4. Open window -> `devo`
5. Open window -> `cd /some/path`
6. /some/path$ -> `rails s --port=3002`
7. Open window -> `cd /other/path`
8. /other/path$ -> `rails s --port=3000`

Can these steps be accomplished in a single script? I'm losing my mind doing these steps every time I restart my system

Comment: What do you mean by tabs? If you are using screen, this can be done in your .screenrc file. If you are using a GUI pseudo-terminal (e.g. gnome-terminal, not sure what the OS X equivalent is called), then a new instance of bash is spawned in each tab. bash is not aware of this.

Comment: Just to clarify, in screen each new tab is a separate instance of bash as well. In either case, bash is unaware of tabs.

Comment: yes. A separate instance of bash so new screen... apple tabs these for us.

Comment: I'm referring to GNU screen which a terminal program. What I'm trying to say is that what you want to do needs to be put in the rc file of whatever X/GUI terminal emulator you are using. bash itself does not have tabs, so a bash script will not do this (unless the bash script spawns the terminal emulator itself).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an applescript. You will just need to run the applescript and it'll do all that for you :

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "memcached" in window 1
    do script "redis-server" -- Each do script opens a new window
    do script "memcached"
    do script "devo"
    do script "cd "
    do script "rails s --port=3002" in window 1 -- does script in last opened window
    do script "cd "
    do script "rails s --port=3000" in window 1 -- does script in last opened window
end tell
```

Save it as an Application so you can double click it to run it. You could also assign it to start on system start or even to a shortcut with a necessary third party program.

Comment: here's how to work with applescripts....http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/applescript-save-script-as-application

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't mind using `xterm` as your terminal, you can do this in your shell scripts:

```
xterm -e $command
```

You can also use the `open` command which is unique to the Mac:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app $command  #Full pathname to $command!
```

For example:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app /usr/bin/vim
```

Works.

You can also use a shell script:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app /home/david/foo.sh
```

What I haven't figured out is how to open a command that requires a command line parameter. If you have to do that, you'll have to stick to `xterm`.

Comment: You can put the command and its parameters in a separate script file, then pass that to `open`.